# Listview displaying only last item

Tags: android, listview

I have written a code to display json items into listview , when i debug the code i can see the data properly , when i am setting the list to the listview i am only seeing the last item

Code i tried :

```
 try {
       foodintervallist.clear();
       final String result = response.body().string();
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
       String data = jsonObject.getString("data");
       JSONArray foodintervalarray = new JSONArray(data);
       HashMap<String, String> menuMap = 
       new HashMap<String, String>();
       for (int j = 0; j < foodintervalarray.length(); j++) {
            String key1 = "";
            JSONObject jsonObject1 =  
            foodintervalarray.getJSONObject(j);
            final String food_interval =  
            jsonObject1.getString(FOOD_INTERVAL);
            if (jsonObject1.isNull(ITEM_NAME)) {
                item_name = "";
            } else {
                item_name = jsonObject1.getString(ITEM_NAME);            
            }

             if (!menuMap.containsKey(food_interval)) {
                  menuMap.put(food_interval, item_name);
             } else {
                  String key = menuMap.get(food_interval);
                  key1=key+","+item_name;
                  menuMap.put(food_interval, key1);
             }

              runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                foodintervallist.add(menuMap);
                                listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(Diet_Order_Activity_New.this, foodintervallist);
                                listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
                                listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
}
```

My BaseAdapter class

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
    activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row, parent, 
    false);
    resultp = fooditervallist.get(position);
    txtFoodInterval = (TextView) 
    itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodInterval);
    txtFoodItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodItems);
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : resultp.entrySet()) {
        String key = entry.getKey();
        String value = entry.getValue();
        txtFoodInterval.setText(key);
        Toast.makeText(activity, "" + key, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        txtFoodItem.setText(value);
        // do what you have to do here
        // In your case, an other loop.
    }

    return itemView;
}
```

I am declaring the foodintervallist globally in my main activity class and also the listviewadapter i am initializing inside oncreate method

I am getting the data inside my arraylist , but i am able to display only the last item , what to do ?

Thanx

Comment: Remove `foodintervallist.add(menuMap);` and add it above `runOnUiThread(...)`.

Comment: foodintervallist has only 1 item that is "menuMap" so it is showing only 1 item in listview.
You should take 2 separate arraylist, 1 for key and 1 for value. Add all the keys and values to their respective arraylists and pass both of them to the adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to check your implementation of Adapter's getCount(). As it is not provided how it looks, I would looked there...
it should be like:

```
public int getCount (){ return fooditervallist.get(0).size() }
```

As you provide a list with only one item. Also I see there some issues in getView() :

1. `fooditervallist.get(position);` --> don't use position there, your list has always only one item therefore use 0 instead otherwise you'll get null pointer
2. your for loop is setting the txtFoodInterval and txtFoodItem with the all values in the Map.Set which might result in all list items having the same value ... instead of for loop you should use a "position" parameter here which is not possible with HashMap as order is not predicable. Use LinkedHashMap instead to have correct order and logic needs to be adjusted

Nevertheless I would implement it differently:

1. JSON parsing - I would create a new object model for holding the data

> class FoodItem {   int interval;  String name;  // getters and setters
>   here  }

2. I would put these items in the list you put your map
3. In adapter you can then use this object quite easily like without any for loop like:

> ```
>  @Override
> public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>     inflater = (LayoutInflater) 
>     activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>     View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_row, parent, false);
>     FoodItem item = fooditervallist.get(position);
>   txtFoodInterval = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodInterval);  
>     txtFoodItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.foodItems);
>   txtFoodInterval.setText(item.interval) ;
>   txtFoodItem.setText(item.name);
>     return itemView;
> ```

}

Also I would recommend to have a look on Retrofit library. It will make your life easier...

Comment: thank you for your suggestions , i created a object class and passed the objects as you mentioned , i also removed the hashmap and now i am directly adding the items into my arraylist<FoodItem> , but i need some more help you , can you help me ?

Comment: No problem, I can help you. Just let me know the details.

Comment: is there is possibility to send it to you privately?

Comment: narahari.arjun@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

put your Hashmap inside the for loop. Because when you use globally the data will be overrided and you get only last item.

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code outside the loop // set adapter outside the loop

```
listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(Diet_Order_Activity_New.this,foodintervallist);
listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```